# Miracast на телевизор c ПК на Win 10 без Wi-Fi адаптера, возможно ли?

Tags: windows, windows-10, wifi, adapter, samsung

У меня есть компьютер, у которого видеокарта поддерживает Miracast (AMD Radeon RX 550), и телевизор Samsungs который так же поддерживает. Я хотел бы использовать его как второй дисплей, но не понимаю, что для этого нужно. Из всего в интернете, я узнал что нужно WiFi адаптер к компютеру, нельзя что ли по роутеру подключить, объязательно адаптер покупать? Если "да", то подключения интернета к компьютеру должно быть строго по этому адаптеру, или можно будет по кабелю?

Стоит windows 10 1903.

Answer (score 4):

Miracast это, изначально, стандарт [for wireless connections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracast) (то бишь беспроводных соединений) между устройствами и дисплеями.

[Вот](https://www.reddit.com/r/miracast/comments/775ks4/can_i_miracast_a_duplicate_screen_through/) [люди](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/miracast-over-ethernet-pc-to-wi-fi-laptop/198b10c9-0694-410b-9673-d4701683e371) с почти идентичной проблемой -- хотят подключить по ethernet ПК к роутеру, а уже с роутера раздавать сигнал устройству-дисплею.
И в обоих случаях, к сожалению, все-таки понадобится беспроводное соединение (WI-FI Direct), чтобы устройства могли обнаружить друг-друга:

> ... Miracast cannot detect devices over Ethernet alone ...

"Miracast не может обнаружить устройства только через Ethernet, без посторонней помощи"

> ... at this time, you're going to need a wireless card in your PC for discovery over Wi-Fi Direct. Once discovery is complete, your actual session can take place over Infrastructure, if the right conditions are met.

"На текущий момент, вам все равно понадобится беспроводное соединение `(wifi-карта/адаптер)` в вашем ПК, для обнаружения устройства через WI-FI Direct. Как только обнаружение успешно произойдет, вы сможете пользоваться ["Miracast по инфраструктуре"](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/surface-hub/miracast-over-infrastructure).

**Если кратко:**
без WI-FI свистка не обойтись.

Comment: извините за заддержку, а можно ли будет к ПК подключиться через кабель, а по адаптеру miracast соеденения?

Comment: @kitsoRik можете пояснить, пожалуйста? Вы хотите управлять пк по miracast?

Comment: нет, я хочу подключить себе второй екран по miracast, но хочу что бы интернет мне подавался на прямую по кабелю, можно ли так?

Comment: @kitsoRik miracast работает локально, так что интернет для использования двойного экрана не нужен. Я думаю это может быть возможным: [здесь используется, правда, chromecast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=miGe5u-LFYQ), а вот [здесь инструкция под миракаст](https://office-watch.com/2014/get-a-wireless-second-screen/). Попробуйте, может получится)